# Converting jquery request to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a call using jQuery:

```
rate=$('#rateit99').rateit('value');
```

I want it to perform using ajax. How could I do?

`rateut99` is the ID of element from where `value` is coming.

Trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19728659).

**UPDATE:**

```
        function x()
        {
        rate=rateit();
        }
    function rateit() 
    {
    var element = $('#rateit99');
    alert("rate it :" + element);
    return element;
  }
```

it alerts : `rate it :[object Object]`

**UPDATE2**

start.php

```
<div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateit99" data-rateit-starwidth="32" data-rateit-starheight="32" style=" position:relative; top:-30px; display:none; left:300px" >
                            </div>
```

login.php: loads `start.php` with above elements.
All the function those are going to be called are in `login.php`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$()` you're getting a `jQuery` object back. So when you're running your script, it's looking for a method called `rateit` inside the jQuery object, which doesn't exist.

Make rateit a standalone method and try it that wat

```
function rateit() {
    var element = $('#rateit99');
    // Do your function here
}
```

EDIT for edited question

```
 function rateit() {
    var element = $('#rateit99');
    alert("rate it :" + element);
    return element;
  }
```

The reason you're getting an `object` back is that `$('#rateit99')` returns the jQuery object that is referencing the DOM object. So let's say this is an HTML input field. It would contain that element. What you probably want is the value contained in that element. So we need to use the jQuery object to get it

```
 function rateit() {
    var element = $('#rateit99').val();
    alert("rate it :" + element);
    return element;
  }
```

Now this function returns the value stored in your HTML element.

Comment: your answer has point to note. But still there's issue. I updated my question please see

Comment: I appreciate your help dude. But still not solved. not it does not receive any value in element. element remains empty

Comment: Post the HTML element with `id="rateid99"` then please

Comment: Are you wanting to do an AJAX call that populates this div?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40437/discussion-between-karimkhan-and-machavity)